# Making an object Teleport back to start upon reaching a certain point (Unity 2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform tf;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.Translate(0, -0.10F, 0 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Hello, I am making a game in which the character gets hit by a car, I want the car to move down, then teleport back up in a loop, that way you need to avoid the cars.  Thank you.

Comment: This question is not about _using the Visual Studio application_ so I have removed your `[visual-studio]` tag. Please ensure you familiarise yourself with the usage of tags by reading their descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me. But, if you just want the car to teleport then you can set the transform.position of the car to the position you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).